# Morphisms between moduli spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-space

Assume that I have two moduli spaces $M_1,M_2$ solving two problems $F_1,F_2:C\to Sets$, think for example about $C=Sch/S$. 
Furthermore I have a morphism $f:M_1\to M_2$ or equivalently a natural transformation $\alpha_f:F_1\to F_2$.

I would like to know how to relate geometric properties of $f$ (e.g. being etale,smooth,open,closed...) with the abstract properties of  $\alpha_f$.

For example take the case where $\alpha_f$ "forgets" some part of the moduli problem; even more concretely assume $F_1(X)=\{A/X$ an abelian variety with some extra structure 1 and extra structure 2$\}$ and $F_2(X)=\{A/X$ an abelian variety with extra structure 1$\}$, then I have the natural transformation $\alpha_f:F_1\to F_2$ corresponding to forgetting the second extra structure. In this example what can I conclude about the corresponding morphism
$f:M_1\to M_2$ (and why)? My intuition tells me that it should be open, but I can't find a rigorous argument for that.

Comment: (I am no expert in the subject, merely a student discovering the topic at the moment) Concretely, we could take $F_1$ the functor of abelian schemes with PEL structures, and $F_2$ that of abelian schemes with PL structures, forgetting about the endomorphism. The corresponding morphism $f:M_1\rightarrow M_2$ is known to be projective, so I believe it would enter in contradiction with your intuition that it is open. I am unaware of any general property we could infer on $f$. (Reference: Genestier, Ngô's lecture on Shimura varieties)